# How to show texts starting from A-D using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I Click on A-D, the table data will have to show only Name starting between  A and D.How can I implement this using jquery.

Thanking u

Comment: bind a click handler and filter them by their name's First character. Try code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an easy-to-understand snippet of how to implement such filtering:

```js
var $table = $('table');

$('.filter').click(filterTable);

function filterTable(e){
  var delimiter = $(this).data('value');
  
  // find all the second cells inside all the rows
  $table.find('tr').find('td:eq(1)').each(function(){
    var tr        = this.parentNode, // get the cell's row
     firstChar = this.textContent[0].toLowerCase(), // important..
        validRow  = firstChar >= delimiter[0] && firstChar <= delimiter[1];

    // show/hide row
    tr.style.display = validRow ? '' : 'none';
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-value="az" class='filter'>All</button>
<button data-value="ad" class='filter'>A-D</button>
<br><br>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Alan</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Charlie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Edward</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Sam</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following as your sample table:

```
<button id="ad">A-D</button>

<table id="personnel" border=1>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td class="pid">1</td>
          <td class="firstname">Alan</td>        
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="pid">2</td>
          <td class="firstname">Alex</td>        
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="pid">3</td>
          <td class="firstname">Charlie</td>        
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="pid">4</td>
          <td class="firstname">Edward</td>        
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pid">5</td>
          <td class="firstname">Jack</td>        
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="pid">6</td>
          <td class="firstname">Sam</td>        
       </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

You can assign a function to your button click, which will: (1) go through each table row and look inside the text inside the "first name" column; and (2) hide those that do not contain the first letter matching the letters of your delimiter (letters A-D).  Function below:

```
   $('#ad').click(function() { 
        var delimiter = 'ABCD';
        $("#personnel td.firstname").each(function(){
            if(curr.indexOf($(this).text().substr(0,1)) != -1){
                 $(this).parent().show();

            }else{
            $(this).parent().hide(); 
            }
        });

        });
```

Here's a [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/u2wzLkaL/3/)